# Open image from gallery and save it to object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Is it possible to opet image gallery on button click so user can select image and put selected iamge into object with other parameters? Actually i want to create some sort of diary with pic and some information, so please i need some guidelines.
This is how object looks for now :

```
var podaci = {VrstaRibe: s_selekt, 
                Tezina: t_tezina, 
                Mamac: m_mamac, 
                DatumUlova: datum, 
                VrijemeUlova: vrijeme, 
                Pribor: p_pribor,
                Lokacija: {
                  Dužina: long,
                  Širina: lat
                },
                Picture:''
              };
```

Comment: On picture parameter are you trying to save only the filepath or you want to save the file image in that object (base64 image)?

Comment: I would recommend checking this plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera
It works for both taking pictures and selecting them from the gallery.

Comment: i couldnt handle it with cordova-plugin-camera, and Carlos that doesnt work